# R: "No line available in input" Error when reading multiple csv files in from a directory

Tags: r, csv, lapply, read.csv

I'm having trouble reading multiple .csv files in from a directory. It's odd because I read in files from two other directories using the same code with no issue immediately prior to running this code chunk.

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\College\\MLMLMasters\\Thesis\\TaggingEffectsData\\DiveStat")

my_dive <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
my_dive

head(my_dive)

if(!require(plyr)){install.packages("plyr")} 

DB = do.call(rbind.fill, lapply(my_dive, function(x) read.csv(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
DB

detach("package:plyr") ### I run this after I have finished creating all the dataframes because I sometimes have issues with plyr and dplyr not playing nice
if(!require(dplyr)){install.packages("dplyr")}
```

Then it throws this error:

> > Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
> > no lines available in input

Which doesn't make any sense because the list.files function works and when I run head(my_dive) I get this output:

```
head(my_dive)
[1] "2004001_R881_TV3.csv"  "2004002_R 57_TV3.csv"  "2004002_R57_TV3.csv"   "2004003_W1095_TV3.csv"
[5] "2004004_99AB_TV3.csv"  "2004005_O176_TV3.csv"
```

Plus the Environment clearly shows that my list is populated with all 614 files as I would expect it to be.

All of the csv file sets have identical file names but different data so they have to be read in as separate data frames from separate directories (not my decision that's just how this dataset was organized). For that reason I can't seem to figure out why this set of files is giving me grief when the other two sets read in just fine with no issues. The only difference should be the working directory and the names of the lists and dataframes. I thought it might be something within the actual directory, but I checked and there are only the .csv files in the directory and the list.files functions works fine. I saw a previous question that was similar to mine but the poster didn't initially use the (pattern = "*.csv") argument and that was the cause for the error. I always use this argument so that seems unlikely to be the cause.

I'm not sure how to go about making this reproduceable but I appreciate any help offered.

Comment: One or more files seems to have an issue while importing. Try to include `print(x)` in `lapply` so that you know which file exactly has an error. Also you can try with `DB <- purrr::map_df(my_dive, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: No empty files? Seems what the error is pointing to and Ronak's approach identifies which one(s).  Converting his ad hoc with validity (has data) checking will help going forward, try catch.

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you and Chris for your inputs. You were correct there were empty files hiding insidiously within the dataset. This is tag data for multiple animals and as it turns out when a tag fails the database builders left an empty structure as a placeholder (*screams in scientist*) so when I pulled the files I got multiple empty files with no headers or data scattered throughout. The other datasets were metadata for the animals so didn't have the issue. Thank you so much for you help